# For Hubspot Linked Service in Azure Data Factory, how to use refresh token to get new access token?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-data-factory, refresh-token

The Azure Data Factory (v2) Hubspot Linked Service requires the normal OAUTH data: client_id, client_secret, access_token and refresh_token, but fails to use the refresh token to get a new access token.

I've read all the documents I could Google and quizzed several devs I know, but can't find a way for Linked Services to refresh expired access tokens.

So, absent docs, is there a way to use OAUTH with ADF Linked Services that doesn't require manually replacing the access token?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Michael, I don't know if this helps, this helped me to do this for BigQuery, not sure about Hubspot but it might be very similar. https://jpd.ms/getting-your-bigquery-refresh-token-for-azure-datafactory-f884ff815a59